# Doctrine: relation keeps returning as proxy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, proxy, doctrine

I have a domain setup as follows:

[image: model]

When I fetch a `Page` the `Blocks` ($blocks) it has a relation to are joined. This is always a `ContentBlock` (there are other types of `Blocks`, but they do not apply for my question). The `ImageContentBlock` is a `ContentBlock` and holds a 1:n relation to `ImageContentBlockImage` ($images). This contains specific information such as $link, $caption etc. It also has a reference to `Image` through $image. This is a ManyToOne relationship.

The problem I encounter is that when I try to fetch the `Image` from the `ImageContentBlockImage` I always get a Proxy object. A problem I cannot solve. I need to this be the real object because the entire object is serialised into sessions (Redis). Proxy objects getting serialised end up as PHP_Incomplete_Object.

Throughout the entire domain I have the `fetch="EAGER"` annotation on all the attributes that hold a relation, all from `Page` to `Image`. These are:
`$page => $blocks`, `$block => (ImageContentBlockImage) $images` and `$images => (Image) $image)`. However i'm still getting Proxy objects.

Image is an extension to a domain entity called File. I guess this has nothing to do with it, but just here to mention it.

I would like to know how I can retrieve a full object rather then a Proxy object for `Image` $image.

===

Now I have a Repository for fetching blocks and which joins the Image & ImageContentBlockImage entities:

```
$qb->select('block', 'imageBlock', 'image')
->from(Block::class, 'block')
->join(ImageContentBlockImage::class, 'imageBlock', Expr\Join::WITH, 'imageBlock.block = block')
->join(Image::class, 'image', Expr\Join::WITH, 'imageBlock.image = image')
->where('block IN (:blocks)')
->setParameter('blocks', $page->getBlocks())
->groupBy('block.id')
->orderBy('block.order');
```

Returning this result still gets me a Proxy object:

```
object(stdClass)[1123]
public '__CLASS__' => string 'Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlockImage' (length=63)
public 'block' => string 'Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlock' (length=58)
public 'image' => string 'Proxy\__CG__\Domain\Domain\File\Image' (length=47)
public 'caption' => null
public 'position' => null
public 'link' => null
public 'order' => int 1
public 'id' => int 4
public 'locale' => null
```

Comment: Just add a query to your repository and explicitly join it.  Plenty of examples in the docs.

Comment: I have updated by OP, to explain and show you my repository and its response.

Comment: $qb->select('block','imageBlock','image') will hydrate the image.

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but no. Still getting proxy objects.

Comment: And I want just the `ContentBlocks`, with the full `Image` object. Not just the images, or only the `ImageContentBlock` objects.

Comment: Your query does not match your dump.  You are querying from blocks so you should have a block object.  Your dump shows a ImageContentBlockImage.  What are doing between the query and the dump?  I'm guessing you want to query FROM ImageContentBlockImage

Comment: `Block` is an abstract class. As is `ContentBlock`, next to `ImageContentBlock` there are others. I wish to get all `ContentBlocks` that are related to the `Page`, with there full `Image` object.

The result i'm showing is indeed a partial, just to show that it does not return the full `Image` object.

Comment: If you say so.  I don't know how you could be querying from an abstract class table.  In any event, consider making a query for just one of whatever it is you are trying to get with a joined image.  Then work from there.  By the way, if you have all your relations defined in Doctrine 2 then there is no need for the WITH clauses.

Comment: Would be a quite expensive query if I have to join each of the blocks separately. What would be the best approach? Perhaps I can shift around with the domain.

Comment: All I was suggesting was that you get one block working then add back in the rest of the query.  With DQL any sort of select(a,b) should hydrate a and be.  The join comment just means that Doctrine already knows how to join object based on your mappings.